# String Value from JSON to empty string or Textbox

Tags: c#, .net, json, string, visual-studio-2012

What I'm trying to do is string specific value from JSON.

JSON link

https://api.dell.com/support/v2/assetinfo/warranty/tags.json?svctags=G88NJX1&apikey=1adecee8a60444738f280aad1cd87d0e

How would i be able to string Specific data from it to a textbox ?
I.E  string  Value for "Asset Tag" & "Warranty"

I already have the code to DeserializeObject and make it show in a text box. I'm just not sure how to pick specific data off it since i don't need most of the rubbish.

```
        string Serial = "G88NJX1";
        WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
        dynamic result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(webClient.DownloadString("https://api.dell.com/support/v2/assetinfo/warranty/tags.json?svctags=" + Serial + "&apikey=1adecee8a60444738f280aad1cd87d0e"));

        textBox1.Text = Convert.ToString(result);
```

Comment: What are you using to deserialize the object?, are you deserializing to a specific object of your creation?

Comment: Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that you are using the Dell warranty API. Instead of decoding their JSON string, create a service reference in your project to them. Put their API in your service reference URL. Back when I wrote this all I had was the IP address and not the DNS name, so my service reference to the Dell API is:

```
http://143.166.84.118/services/assetservice.asmx?WSDL
```

Here is how I get the warranty data (and other stuff). It uses the API's EntitlementData object to store info.

```
            string ServiceTag = "your service tag here";
            DellServiceReference.AssetServiceSoapClient svc = new DellServiceReference.AssetServiceSoapClient();
            Guid DellFeeder = new Guid("12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456789012");
            DellServiceReference.Asset[] assets = svc.GetAssetInformation(DellFeeder, "dellwarrantycheck", ServiceTag);

            // go through each warranty
            DellServiceReference.EntitlementData[] entitlements = assets[0].Entitlements;
            foreach (DellServiceReference.EntitlementData warr in entitlements)
            {
                DateTime start = warr.StartDate;
                DateTime stop = warr.EndDate;
                // do stuff with this
            }
```

Comment: It worked. But how would i be able to get the serviceLevelDecription? i.e   "Complete Care"  "Next Day..... blah blah

Comment: Actually its only returning the warranty Start and End date for the Dell Digital Delivery. I need the rest of Services Like Next Day Support, and Gold Technical Support or ProSupport for End Users that come up for this asset when i go to their site.

Comment: It may be that the direct IP I go to could be deprecated. If you use your service API URL that you have, are you getting a different set of objects from the WSDL?

Comment: i think it is. What it seems like its doing is its grabbing the last warranty service which will always be P, Dell Digital Delivery                                                                if you navigate to the link i have you will see what im talking about

Comment: Ah, I see. Once you pull all the entitlements, filter by the entitlement type of extended to get the ProSupport ones. There is a service level description within the entitlement that has NBD support, and there is also an int in the servicelevelgroup that might give you a non-string based way to filter and a consistent result if Dell changes their naming scheme.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with this:

```
JArray obj = (JArray)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(yourJSONString);
object a = obj[0]["theKeyYouNeed"];
```

Then you convert to the type you need.

Hope that helps

Comment: i did try this but how would i be able to display this into a text box?

Comment: Cannot convert type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject' to 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray'